# Can someone recommend an open source MQTT broker that combines persistence and high throughput

Tags: message-broker

I am running an IoT solution that relies on sending 4 MQTT messages / second qith qos=1 from hundreds of devices to a central broker. An analyser component subscribes to all topics from all devices with cleanSession=false, processes and stores the messages in a DB. Like this no messages are lost in case of interruptions of the analyser process, e.g. for redeployment.

In our current production configuration mosquitto can handle the load of 4x300 = 1200 msg / sec.

I would like to find an MQTT broker that can scale horizontally and handle, 10k or even 100k msg/sec with persistence.

In a load testing activity we try to scale the system up to 2500 devices i.e. 4x2500 = 10k messages / sec. We tested mosquitto, VerneMQ and EMQX and observed that all of them can handle 10k msg / sec easily without persistence (cleanSession=true), but when persistence is activated (cleanSession=false) the throughput drops to values between 300 and 2000 msg/sec.